# Is there a quick way (using Linq) to filter the list by the top of each version number in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

I have an IEnumerable object which has version details as one of the properties. It contains values like

```
1.0,1.1,2.0,2.1,2.2,3.0
```

I would like to get a max of each version that is

```
1.1,2.2,3.0
```

I can do it using a loop. But is there a quicker/cleaner way to do the same thing using Linq? 
Following is the class detail:

```
 public class FileVersionDetail
    {

        public int? ReturnTypeId { get; set; }
        public string FileTemplateName { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }
        public string VersionNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Group by floor of the version number and then get the max of each group.

Comment: You might consider not using strings to store your version number. There's a version number type that was designed to solve this problem; use it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

putting Rotem's comment as code.

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetMaxVersions(IEnumerable<FileVersionDetail> files) 
{
        //1. Group the list by base/floor version numbers.
        var groupedByBaseVersion = files.Select(f => f.VersionNumber).GroupBy(f => f.Split('.')[0]);

        //2. Find the max in each group.
        return groupedByBaseVersion.Select(g => g.ToArray().Max());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was on phone. Note that this makes a possibly dangerous assumption that `VersionNumber` is a string that always represents a decimal number and nothing else. If that is guaranteed to be the case, it may as well be a `decimal` and not a `string`, that will be safer.  Also note that your `.Max()` is operating on `string`, and is thus returning the ordinal maximum, not the numerical maximum, though in this case I can't find an example where that breaks.

Comment: true, OP's model has the version number as string, also example versions follow the same structure,

Comment: Absolutely. The warning was directed at OP, not your answer.

Comment: `GetMaxVersions(new[] { new FileVersionDetail { VersionNumber = "1.100" }, new FileVersionDetail { VersionNumber = "1.20" }};`)` spits out `"1.20"`.  Is this acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [System.Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netframework-4.8) class for this purpose since it already has a nice version string parser, and comparison logic pre-built.

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetMaxVersions(IEnumerable<FileVersionDetail> files) 
{
    return files
      .Select(f=>new Version(f.VersionNumber))
      .GroupBy(f=>f.Major)
      .Select(f=>f.Max().ToString());
}
```

Comment: Where did you get `Version` from? A how does it have a constructor that takes the OP's custom type?

Comment: It comes from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netframework-4.8, and the constructor takes a string in that format.

Comment: Nowhere it is mentioned that OP has the file path, or that the file even exists locally on the OPs system.

Comment: Type `(new string[] { "1.0", "1.1", "2.0", "2.1", "2.2", "3.0" }).Select(f => new Version(f)).GroupBy(f => f.Major).Select(f => f.Max().ToString()).ToArray()` into the C# interactive window, REPL, LINQPad or whatever your favorite C# tool is, and it'll return `string[3] { "1.1", "2.2", "3.0" }`

Comment: @Rotem Hopefully my edits have cleared up any confusion.  Originally `files` was supposed to be an `IEnumerable<string>`, but I changed it to be an `IEnumerable<FileVersionDetail>` instead since that was the OPs class he provided.